# add_action,add_filter,user_can ect in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have developed wordpress  for days,but I have found no way to these like:add_action,add_filter,user_can, I don't know what are the functions they refere to.
worse still,I don't know the parameter,today I want add a column to user list table admin panel,I fortunatelly found a tutorial, here is the code

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'add_user_column');
function add_user_column( $columns){
     $columns['available_stickers'] = __('Stickers Available', 'available_stickers');
     return $columns;   
}
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column',  'add_user_column_value', 10, 3);
function add_user_column_value( $value, $column_name, $user_id ){
     if ( 'available_sticker' == $column_name)
          $value = get_user_meta($user_id,"available_stickers",true);
     return $value;
}
```

Even thought I made it, but I don't know where  the parameter `manage_users_columns` comes or why I should use `manage_users_columns`  but not other code? Puzzled
and also they have matched code like `apply_filter` etc.
some one can help me out of the maze,oops!

Comment: It's all in the Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation

Comment: install IDE like eclipse and you will easy find the function definitions and documentation

Comment: I think stevenlee is moreso struggling with the concept of hooks rather than trying to find a definition of the corresponding functions. At least I tried to answer below

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is beautifully designed because most of the actions it does are not executed directly, but through what are called *actions* and *filters*. This gives you, the developer, a possibility to *hook* onto any of these operations. Hooking means you can squeeze your own logic right in the middle of WP's logic, in a very clean way, only by declaring that you want things to be done where the corresponding hooks are used. More precisely:

**Actions**

So, for example, when a post is saved, WordPress does not just save the post, it does it by executing this line:

```
do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post );
```

This is a way to give a *name* to this action (save_post). That means two things :

1) you can execute the exact same action by using the same line of code somewhere else.

2) you can add *your own logic to be executed during this action*. How? just by "adding" your custom functions to the action, like this :

```
add_action('save_post', 'name_of_the_function_you_want_to_execute_when_post_is_saved');
```

So 'save_post' is the name of the hook, `add_action` gives you the possibility to add your own function to the action for this hook and `do_action` actually executes the action.

**Filters**

Filters are similar to actions, but instead of being used when executing a command, they are used to treat a value, an object, a string or some text (when "filtering" it). Again, instead of just manipulating objects and strings in such a way that you would have no other possibility than dive into the core code to access it, WordPress cleverly does many of its "filtering" operations with a special action called `apply_filters()`. This gives you the possibility, like for actions, to actually *add your own filters* to the filters already applied. So when showing the content of a post, WP would execute :

```
apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

The name of the hook is `the_content`. If you use :

```
add_filter('the_content', 'your_function_to_execute_to_further_filter_content');
```

you can have a function named `your_function_to_execute_to_further_filter_content()`that can take the content as a parameter and return the filtered version of it after whatever treatment you wish to apply to it. Then this treatment will get applied anywhere in WP where the hook `the_content` is used to execute these filters (including WP default ones, plug-ins filters that were added to the same hook, and your own).

So here, you are using these hooks so you can interfere with WP operations without messing WP core code. You declare the extra operations you wish to execute and you let WP aware of this. WP will then have the courtesy to execute your functions everytime the corresponding hook action or filter is being executed.

Comment: oh,thans for your answers,I have got it,but I;m still  puzzled:you gave me an example of 

do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post ); I want to know whether a real function of 

save_post exists,I use zend studio just searched save_post,but it hits me,it doesn't appear 

a function,there just are the applications of save_post.well, if this is not a function(I 

follow your explanation,I draw conclusion that save_post is just a id or to say a name for 

developers for secondary development ), I'm really pity that how does it work to save the 

post??also thanx in advance!